# Alpha anywhere : How do I check if the cookies exist or not?

Tags: cookies

I want to check if the cookies exist or not. So I am using the code below which I get from A5 Documentation.

```
dim _temp_cookie as c

        if Context.Request.HasCookie(_temp_cookie) then
            js = Context.Request.GetCookie(_temp_cookie)
        else
            dim newCookie as System::Web::HttpCookie = new System::Web::HttpCookie(_temp_cookie)
            sql = <<%sql%
                DECLARE @id INT
                DECLARE @tempin VARCHAR(14)
                EXEC dbo.bfcm_sp_create_order_pin @id = @id OUTPUT, 
                @tempin = @tempin OUTPUT;
                SELECT @tempin      
                %sql%

            conn.Execute(sql)
            rs = conn.ResultSet

            newCookie.HttpOnly = .t.
            newCookie.Value= rs.data(1)
            Context.Response.AppendCookie(newCookie)
            js = newCookie.Value
        end if

conn.Close()
e.javascript = "{Dialog.object}.setValue('tempid',"+js+");"
```

I execute this code on server-side events **onDialogInitialize** but every time I refresh the page, I get the new cookie number. What I understand about the cookies is the value will only change when it expires or we clear up the cookies in the browser.
I have the IF statement to check `if context.request.Hascookie(_temp_cookie)` but I think I did something wrong in my code that it reads the `else` every time I refresh the page. I need an eagle eyes to check my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot to initialize the `_temp_cookie`. I have declared it to a `c` type but it is an empty variable should I say.
Problem solved with:

```
dim _temp_cookie as c = "_temp_cookie"
```

or the name can be changed to another name with quotes `" "`